# Possible animationdrawable with path?

Tags: android, animation, animationdrawable

I am new with Animations and have my first animationdrawable finish.
Only two PNGs but it runs.
But i have not found a solution for move the Picture or rotate them.
Is this posible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the view animation system to perform tweened animation on Views. 
Follow the link to learn more:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html